# Concatenate multiple fasta files into one file per unique entry

Tags: fasta, text-processing

I have eight fasta files, one per gene, with 106 fasta entries per file, like this:

gene1.fasta:

```
>sample1_434564
GATCTCGTAGATGTGA
>sample2_2346764
GATCTCGTAGATGTGA
```

gene2.fasta:

```
>sample1_532345
ATGCTGTGAAGTA
>sample2_6040103
ATGCTGTGAAGTA
```

What I want to do is create one fasta file per sample so that I get all gene sequences for that sample in one file. As you can see, the sample ID is the same before the `_` in the fasta headers, but the rest is unique for each fasta file.

Is  there any way to do this with `awk` or other command-line tools?

Desired output:

Sample1.fasta

```
>gene1
GATCTCGTAGATGTGA
>gene2
ATGCTGTGAAGTA
```

Sample2.fasta

```
>gene1
GATCTCGTAGATGTGA
>gene2
ATGCTGTGAAGTA
```

Comment: What operating system are you using? Do you have access to GNU tools? Is this a Linux machine or something else?

Comment: @terdon It's on linux yes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this simply enough in `awk`:

```
$ awk -F'_' '{
               split(FILENAME,n,/\./); 
               if(/^>/){
                  sample=$1; 
                  sub(/>/,"",sample); 
                  $0=">"n[1]
               }
               print > sample".fasta"
             }' gene1.fasta gene2.fasta ... geneN.fasta
```

If I run this on the two files you gave, I get:

```
$ cat sample1.fasta 
>gene1
GATCTCGTAGATGTGA
>gene2
ATGCTGTGAAGTA

$ cat sample2.fasta 
>gene1
GATCTCGTAGATGTGA
>gene2
ATGCTGTGAAGTA
```

#### Explanation

- `-F'_'` : set the field separator to `_` as an easy hack that lets us use `$1` for the sample name (`sample_NNN`, so `sample` will be `$1` and `NNN` will be `$2`).
- `split(FILENAME,n,/\./);` : `FILENAME` always holds the name of the file currently being processed. Here, we are splitting it on `.` to get the gene's name. **This assumes all of your files are named `$geneName.fasta`.** The `split` creates the array `n` whose 1st element, `n[1]` is the gene name.
- `if(/^>/){` : if this is a fasta header line.
- `sample=$1` : set the variable `sample` to the sample's name. See the first note about `-F'_'`.
- `sub(/>/,"",sample);` : remove the `>` from the `sample` variable. We don't want that in the file name.
- `$0=">"n[1]` : set the current line to be `>` and the gene name.
- `print > sample".fasta"` : print each (modified) line into the appropriate file name.